# Позиционирование секций

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите, каким образом сверстать данный блок с сохранением пропорций?
Bootstrap игнорирует указанную ширину, если задать её этому блоку.

[image: Макет]

```
    <!-- SECTION CONTENT -->
    <section id="wrapper text-center">

    <section class="main_row" id="content_first">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-lg-12 content_header">
              <h1 class="content_header_image main_row_one">SUMMER'S COMING</h1>
              <div class="content_header_line"></div>
              <p class="content_header_text">TRIMM YOUR SHEEPS</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section><!-- /content_first -->

   <section class="main_row" id="content_second">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="row main_row">
         <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
           <h2>Best articles in this month</h2>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </section>
    </section><!-- /wrapper -->
```

Comment: добавьте пример вашего кода [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял ты пытаешься задать размер враппперу . В первую очередь тубе надо переделать структуру:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <section class="main_row">
    </section>
    <section class="main_row" id="content_second">
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если нужно уменьшить контейнер тогда просто задаешь нужную ширину контейнеру.
И тут я думаю можно обойтись без айдишников.

Comment: Wrapper занимает 10 столбцов. Как их расположить именно по середине страницы? Прочитал все инструкции по фреймворку, ответа на вопрос не нашел.

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо